# How can you make two or more turtles perform a task at the same time?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

My goal for this program was to get used to python's built-in "turtle" method. My goal was to program four (ninja) turtles to walk simultaneously in a square. While there were no absolute errors in my program, I wanted the program to show turtles walking at the same time (not running into each other). At first, I tried to separate the four variables with commas on the same line- but that did not change anything. Alternatively, I used "+" to separate each variable- which does not work. I then looked up how to move two turtles at once. However, as most of those programs deal with racing, certain methods did not work.

```
import turtle

leonardo = turtle.Turtle()
rafael = turtle.Turtle()
michelangelo = turtle.Turtle()
donatello = turtle.Turtle()

leonardo.shape("turtle")
rafael.shape("turtle")
michelangelo.shape("turtle")
donatello.shape("turtle")

michelangelo.left(90)
donatello.right(90)
leonardo.forward(250)
rafael.backward(250)
donatello.forward(250)
michelangelo.forward(250)

# Better if I could make all four turtles turn at the same time
michelangelo.left(45), leonardo.left(135), rafael.right(45), donatello.left(135)

turtle_speed = 1

angle = float(input("Which angle would you like the turtles to face? "))

for i in range(1):

    leonardo.speed(1)

    leonardo.pencolor("light green")

    leonardo.forward(353.5533905932738)
    leonardo.left(angle)
    leonardo.forward(353.5533905932738)
    leonardo.left(angle)
    leonardo.forward(353.5533905932738)
    leonardo.left(angle)
    leonardo.forward(353.5533905932738)
    leonardo.left(angle)

    rafael.pencolor("gold")

    rafael.forward(353.5533905932738)
    rafael.left(angle)
    rafael.forward(353.5533905932738)
    rafael.left(angle)
    rafael.forward(353.5533905932738)
    rafael.left(angle)
    rafael.forward(353.5533905932738)
    rafael.left(angle)

    michelangelo.pencolor("turquoise")

    michelangelo.left(90)
    michelangelo.forward(353.5533905932738)
    michelangelo.left(angle)
    michelangelo.forward(353.5533905932738)
    michelangelo.left(angle)
    michelangelo.forward(353.5533905932738)
    michelangelo.left(angle)
    michelangelo.forward(353.5533905932738)
    michelangelo.left(angle)

    donatello.pencolor("white")

    donatello.forward(353.5533905932738)
    donatello.left(angle)
    donatello.forward(353.5533905932738)
    donatello.left(angle)
    donatello.forward(353.5533905932738)
    donatello.left(angle)
    donatello.forward(353.5533905932738)
    donatello.left(angle)


turtle.done()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Multiple Turtles Moving (seemingly) Simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056498/python-multiple-turtles-moving-seemingly-simultaneously)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to have each turtle move a little bit at a time.  I made some changes that show how to do it with movement:

```
import turtle

leonardo = turtle.Turtle()
rafael = turtle.Turtle()
michelangelo = turtle.Turtle()
donatello = turtle.Turtle()

ninjas = [ leonardo, rafael, michelangelo, donatello ]

angle = 0

for t in ninjas:
  t.shape("turtle") 
  t.right(angle)
  t.forward(250)
  angle += 90


turtle_speed = 1
leonardo.pencolor("light green")
rafael.pencolor("gold")
michelangelo.pencolor("turquoise")
donatello.pencolor("white")

angle = float(input("Which angle would you like the turtles to face? "))

turns = 4
while turns>0:
  turns -= 1  
  move = 350
  while move>0:
    for t in ninjas:
      t.forward(5)
    move -= 5

  for t in ninjas:
    t.left(angle)

turtle.done()
```