# How do I make all the different objects draw(run) at the Same Time with: for loop

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
import time
import random
import turtle

turtle.penup()
turtle.setposition(-350, 175)
turtle.pendown()
colors = ('Sea green1', 'cyan',)
turtle.bgcolor('black')

for i in range(240):
   turtle.pencolor(colors[i % 2])
   turtle.width(i / 80)
   turtle.forward(i)
   turtle.left(90.899)
   turtle.speed(30000000000)
   
turtle.penup()
turtle.setposition(350, 175)
turtle.pendown()
colors_2 = ('red2', 'orange', 'yellow')

for i in range(150):
   turtle.pencolor(colors_2[i % 3])
   turtle.width(i / 60)
   turtle.forward(i)
   turtle.left(59)
   turtle.speed(30000000000)
   
turtle.penup()
turtle.setposition(-350, -175)
turtle.pendown()
colors_3 = ('white', 'navajo white', 'salmon1', 'lemon chiffon', 'tan1')

for i in range(200):
   turtle.pencolor(colors_3[i % 5])
   turtle.width(i / 65)
   turtle.forward(i)
   turtle.left(71)
   turtle.speed(300000000000)
   
turtle.penup()
turtle.setposition(350, -175)
turtle.pendown()
colors_4 = ('red', 'purple', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'yellow')

for i in range(150):
   turtle.pencolor(colors_4[i % 6])
   turtle.width(i / 60)
   turtle.forward(i)
   turtle.left(59)
   turtle.speed(30000000000)
   
turtle.penup()
turtle.setposition(-125,0)
turtle.pendown()

albert = turtle.Turtle()
albert.speed(10)
albert.color("white")
albert.speed(0)

briana = turtle.Turtle()
briana.speed(10)
briana.color("yellow")
briana.speed(0)

chloe = turtle.Turtle()
chloe.speed(10)
chloe.color("blue")
chloe.speed(0)

daniel = turtle.Turtle()
daniel.speed(10)
daniel.color("orange")
daniel.speed(0)

emily = turtle.Turtle()
emily.speed(10)
emily.color("pink")
emily.speed(0)


def drawCircles(t, num, size, delta):
  for i in range(num):
    t.circle(size)
    size = size - delta
  for i in range (repeat):
    drawCircles(t, num, size, delta)
    t.right(360 / repeat)


# Put it all together!
drawCircleRing(albert, 10, 100, 4, 10)
drawCircleRing(briana, 4, 100, 10, 10)
drawCircleRing(chloe, 4, 100, 5, 10)
drawCircleRing(daniel, 4, 100, 19, 10)
drawCircleRing(emily, 4, 100, 20, 10)
turtle.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Turns out, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056498/python-multiple-turtles-moving-seemingly-simultaneously) is much better than the dupe.